# Programming real time combat

Tags: c++, game-mechanics

I am programming a lot of turn based game, all text, but how do you program real time combat in games, like an rts, or a shooter, where everything is not input based

Comment: With a big loop... you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: Do some research. This is a VERY broad topic.

Answer (score 3):

Real Time games are just Turn Based games where the turns go by really fast.  Also a "turn" doesn't pause to wait for input, instead either polling keyboard/gamepad/mouse states or getting the information via events.

The game loop is your friend.  [Here](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) is a more detailed explanation of some of the basic concepts and techniques involved.

As a side note, making a real time text based game is going to be difficult due to the nature of the console window.  I'd recommend reading up on some basic graphics/input handling so you have a good platform to work from.  SDL is a good choice if you want to dive in and [Lazy Foo'](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) has some excellent tutorials on the matter.  As a bonus, the game loop structure is used in a number of the tutorials so you'll have some actual implementation to experiment with.

Comment: MUDs / text-based adventures are good examples of real-time text loops.

Answer (score 0):

Event handling in OOP or a loop if you're using a more traditional language.

Comment: Well even an event handling system needs a loop as far as I know ;)

Comment: yes, that's correct, I guess I was trying to add a tiny bit of detail to the generality here....